# Solving simple textbook proof

Tags: inequality

It looks silly simple but somehow I am not able to factor so that I could show that the equality holds:

How can I prove that this equality holds:

$$\frac{1}{x^4}+1\geq \frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x}$$

Given

$$x>0$$

I also thought about using contrapositive to prove it by assuming that $x<0$, but I still get stuck, could someone show me the steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying $x^4$ gives us that we need to show $x^4-x^3-x+1 \ge 0$

Note

$$x^4-x^3-x+1 \ge 0 \Leftrightarrow (x^3-1)(x-1)=(x-1)^2(x^2+x+1) \ge 0$$

$$x^2+x+1=(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4} >0$$

Comment: @mathlove Right, is it fixed?

Comment: Why do I not see that straight away.... aaaaaa

Comment: Nice +1. $(x^3-1)(x-1)\ge0$ suffices, as the factors always have the same sign.